# Building a realtime clock in iOS update with NSTimer or performSelector?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimer

I want to display the real time in a label and I found two approaches to update `NSDate`:

The `performSelector` approach:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self updateTime];
}

- (void)updateTime
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    label.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    //call updateTime again after 1 second
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

The `NSTimer` approach:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}    

- (void)updateTime 
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    label.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Which one is the better, more performant and reliable method?

Comment: It is expensive to create a `NSDateFormatter`. Create it once and reuse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this is not quite related to Xcode.

Secondly: more performant? **Seriously?** When it's called **one time a second?** Just forget worrying about efficiency.

Thirdly, they're equivalent, but I don't see the need for the recursion-like self-invocation of the method. Just go with `NSTimer`, it's exactly why it was invented.

Comment: There's no recursion in either of these cases. `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is just scheduling a future invocation of itself which is managed by the run loop; There's no danger of blowing up the stack.

Comment: @ipmcc I didn't write it was going to blow up the stack, did I. (But you are right that technically there's no recursion.) My main problem with that is readability and the abuse of the tool.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers H2CO3 and ipmcc. I will go with `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 1):

A timer does its best to perform on a "fixed" schedule, ie every second.

On the other hand, calling `performSelector:afterDelay` at the end of a function that took, say, 500ms to execute, will result in your function being called every 1500ms (the 500ms it took to execute + the 1s delay).

Thus the timer is more reliable. As H2CO3 said, forget about performance, it's a non-problem with such simple tasks.

Comment: Thx for your explanation. I noticed if I use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5` the seconds still run correct (every second). Why is that?

Comment: You're updating twice in a second. It's just you can't see it, because the text remains the same during two consecutive runs.